# How to limit users to make only one entry per day into a certain form?

Tags: javascript, angular6

I created, under angular, a form to fill a calendar (agenda), but I want that the customer can enter only 1 event per day. He can not add a second event until the next day. I would like to set restrictions.
My forms look like this:

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" (click)="ngxSmartModalService.getModal('myModal').open()">Take stock of the Day</button>

<ngx-smart-modal #myModal identifier="myModal">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <h2>Enregistrer un nouveau Event</h2>
            <form [formGroup]="calForm" (ngSubmit)="onSaveEvent()">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">Message</label>
                    <input type="text" id="title" class="form-control" formControlName="title">
                </div>   
      
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="color">Couleur</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="color" formControlName="color">
                        <option>Bad Day</option>
                        <option>Medium Day</option>
                        <option>Good Day</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <button class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="calForm.invalid" type="submit" (click)="myModal.close()">Enregistrer</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</ngx-smart-modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your post actually does not contain a question :-), and it is a bit vague. Nevertheless:

You have tagged your post with `Javascript` and `Angular`. This makes me believe that you eventually mix up *back-end* and *front-end* functionality:

The restrictions you mention can only be implemented in a *back-end* for several reasons. For example, you want them to be per-user. This inevitably means that a back-end must identify the user (login), search (a database) for the last entry of that user, get the data / time of this entry, and decide if that user is allowed to make a new entry again.

If you would try to implement your restrictions at the *front-end*, which would be difficult anyway, a user could just make an entry, then immediately open another browser software and make a second entry. The second browser would not know what actions have been done in the first one. Even easier, a user could make one entry in his browser, then clear the browser data (including cookies, super-cookies, flash cookies, DOM storage and so on), then make a second entry.

Summary: Such restrictions are typically implemented in the back-end, using the usual languages like `Perl`, `PHP` and so on, but not `Javascript` (unless your back-end is written in Node.js or something similar, which I doubt).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually on the back-end level. You need a database solution to do such reliable restrictions - where you could store the date the form was submitted.

However, you could achieve this on the client-side too but just won't be reliable as they could alter the data.

You could use [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store the date/time the form was submitted and prevent the form being submitted within a day. I don't know angular so I give you a vanilla js solution which you can adapt to angular.

Here is an example;

```
<form onsubmit="onFormSubmit()">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function onFormSubmit(){
    var submittedDate = localStorage.getItem('submitted-date');

    if(!submittedDate){
        // Submit your form here because this is the first time or there is nothing in localstorage
        submitForm();
    } else {
        var timestamp = new Date().getTime(); // Unix timestamp
        var timeDiff = Math.abs(submittedDate - timestamp); // Calculate difference between current timestamp and saved timestamp
        var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); // Get day from timestamp

        if(diffDays < 1){
            return; // It's been less than a day
        } else {
            // It has been more than a day from last submission - Allow form submission
            submitForm();
        }

    }
}

function submitForm(){
    // Submit form
    // Save current timestamp to localstorage
    localStorage.setItem('submitted-date', JSON.stringify(new Date().getTime()));
}
```

But, I will repeat. **This is not reliable!** As, one could easily delete/alter localstorage using dev tools on a browser.